# Create Primary Key where combination of columns are unique

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key

I am creating a table

[image]

where combination of all three columns are unique.

How would I create a primary key from all three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold CTRL and click on each one of the table column definitions. Then, right click and select Set Primary Key